# Change proportional constraint programmatically in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I have a a popup view, that I want to it to have different size in portrait and landscape case of iPad. Here is my code, but it's not working well,

I want it to have width with 60% and 40% of superview width when it's in portrait and landscape.

And heigh with 50% and 50% of superview height when it's in portrait and landscape.

```
func popupConfiguration(){
    switch UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom {
    case .tv, .carPlay, .unspecified, .phone:
        break
    case .pad:
        if UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation == .portrait || UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation == .portraitUpsideDown {
            popupView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.6).isActive = true
            popupView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
        } else {
            popupView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.4).isActive = true
            popupView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
        }
    @unknown default:
        break
    }
}
```

And then, should I add it to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or `viewWillAppear`?
many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement [`viewWillTransition(to:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontentcontainer/1621466-viewwilltransition). Look to see whether the new size is portrait (height is bigger) or landscape (width is bigger). Replace your constraints accordingly; if you do that in the transition coordinator's animation, the change will be animated along with the rotation.

Comment: Thanks, but the way that I write new constrains is right?

Comment: Yes and no. I said "replace". You need to swap out the old constraints and replace them with the new ones.